# TYPO3 tx_news can't handle the related news category in url on detail view page

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

On my page I have couple of categories and different detail view for each of them. On my list view everything looks ok and every news point to correct detail view. The problem is related news on detail view page. If my news is from `category1` url looks like this:

```
www.example.com/category1/article/news-title
```

All related news on this page has the same category in url (`category1`) even if news pointed to different category (e.g. `category2`)

Any suggestion what is wrong?

P.S. I'm using standard configuration of `tx_news`

My configuration: TYPO3 6.2.27; tx_news 3.2.6

```php
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[day]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[month]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[year]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                ),
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'autoUpdate' => 1,
                'expireDays' => 180,
            )
        ),
    ),

    'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_category',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    '72' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    '77' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    '78' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    '79' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    '33' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
    '75' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',
),
```

Comment: Can you add your realurl configuration for news you are using?

Comment: How do you get the category as a part of URL? Or is it the name of the detail page?

Comment: It's the part of detail page title in URL

Comment: Ah, I understand now, since there are news categories as well, so that is why I was confused. Ok, how does your list view know which news should go to which detail view? I am more surprised it works there that it doesn't in the detail view.

Comment: I set proper category on every list and one on detail view and it works like a charm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125353/discussion-between-jozef-spisiak-and-adrian).